# Contract Execution Completed But Transaction Failed

Tags: etherscan, bsc

I have a transaction issued to a contract that shows as having completed execution successfully, but the transaction still fails:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x0c6ae70995d8dbd8e6db2aad218c85248b29b716318cfecbf7b46115489ae778

I'm catching the error in my node.js script and it looks like the following:

```
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xec84de18284e79786fb934bebbd7ed4336bcbf50f91763c1ca99827233d54a4d",
  "blockNumber": 7677297,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 346555,
  "from": "0x3ab63726fc1725bb5a56610ef99dbb43ca207147",
  "gasUsed": 346555,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x755cb57cc2bf580741997d714bd15d6850e768d2",
  "transactionHash": "0x0c6ae70995d8dbd8e6db2aad218c85248b29b716318cfecbf7b46115489ae778",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "type": "0x0",
  "events": {}
}
```

Why is the transaction failing if the contract is completing successfully?  I've seen cases where I've run out of gas, or the contract reverted for some reason, but that isn't happening in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it must have been a caching issue in bscscan.  When I navigate to the page now it shows the transaction as reverted.